# NDSolve Error "message text not found"

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, output-formatting, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve a nonlinear PDE - 1D diffusive heat equation.
I'm not sure what is wrong (am new to Mathematica).

I'm trying to use https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#243862001 as a reference.

```
parameters = {v -> -0.000001, DT -> 0.000000143, rho -> 1000, 
c -> 4200, eta -> 0.001002};
HEATIMP = {-D[u[r, t], t] - v.D[u[r, t], r] + (DT/r^2).D[r^2. D[u[r, t], r], 
  r] + (12. eta)/(rho.c).(v/r).(v/r)} /. parameters
BCE1 = DirichletCondition[u[r, t] == 1, r == 2];
BCE2 = DirichletCondition[u[r, t] == 0, r == 1];
BCTot = {BCE1, BCE2};
ic = {u[r, 0] == 0};
heatdist = NDSolve[{HEATIMP == 0, BCTot, ic}, u, {r, 1, 2}, {t, 0.000001, 100}]
```

Gives the message:

```
NDSolve::t parsing failed: -- Message text not found -- ({{-u$6579-(-1.*10^-6).u$6580+(1.43*10^-7/r^2).(2. r^1. u$6580+r^2. u$6581)+0.012024/1000.4200.(-(1.*10^-6/r)).(-(1.*10^-6/r))}})
```

I had this solved on Mathematica 9 using a different framework (that did not appear to be robust enough). However I would like to use the features and formalism introduced in Mathematica 10 and 11. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Replace `HEATIMP = {-D[u[r, t], t] - v.D[u[r, t], r] + (DT/r^2).D[r^2. D[u[r, t], r], 
  r] + (12. eta)/(rho.c).(v/r).(v/r)}` by `HEATIMP = (-D[u[r, t], t] - 
    v D[u[r, t], r] + (DT/r^2) D[r^2. D[u[r, t], r], 
      r] + (12. eta)/(rho c) (v/r) (v/r)) `

Comment: The fact that the message text is not found is a bug and I'll have a look at that. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: The missing message will be fixed in the next release (12.1)